Highcharts export server - examples not working
Highcharts has an export server and they had some examples in their GitHub repo:
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/tests/node/scenarios/custom_code_from_string.json
If you copy any of the examples and call the export server https://export.highcharts.com
it gets back as a bad request.
This is not working:
{export:
 {
  // JSONDATA
 }
}

This is working:
{
  // JSONDATA
}

The problem is the export server only accept the export object body. So if I want to use the callback I can't cause it is in a different block.
Here is my simple console app getting image from the export server:
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace chartImageScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string apiUrl = "https://export.highcharts.com/";

            // 400 Bad Request cause the JSON structure and the custom logic in it.
            //string jsonData = "{\r\n  \"export\": {\r\n    \"options\": {\r\n      \"chart\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"column\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"title\": {\r\n        \"text\": \"Custom code (from string)\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"yAxis\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"title\": {\r\n            \"text\": \"Primary axis\"\r\n          }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"opposite\": true,\r\n          \"title\": {\r\n            \"text\": \"Secondary axis\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"plotOptions\": {\r\n        \"column\": {\r\n          \"borderRadius\": 5\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"series\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"data\": [1, 3, 2, 4]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"data\": [324, 124, 547, 221],\r\n          \"yAxis\": 1\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"customLogic\": {\r\n    \"allowCodeExecution\": true,\r\n    \"allowFileResources\": true,\r\n    \"customCode\": \"Highcharts.setOptions({chart:{events:{render:function (){this.renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',75,50,20,20).add();}}}});\"\r\n  }\r\n}";

            // Gets image and 200 result but the custom logic is obviously missing.
            string jsonData = "{\r\n    \"options\": {\r\n      \"chart\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"column\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"title\": {\r\n        \"text\": \"Custom code (from string)\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"yAxis\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"title\": {\r\n            \"text\": \"Primary axis\"\r\n          }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"opposite\": true,\r\n          \"title\": {\r\n            \"text\": \"Secondary axis\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"plotOptions\": {\r\n        \"column\": {\r\n          \"borderRadius\": 5\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"series\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"data\": [1, 3, 2, 4]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"data\": [324, 124, 547, 221],\r\n          \"yAxis\": 1\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                // Adding necessary headers
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Sending POST request with JSON data
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "relativeAddress");
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                // Checking if request was successful
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Reading response content as a byte array
                    var imageData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                    // Saving the image file
                    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync($"chart_image_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.png", imageData);

                    Console.WriteLine("Image saved successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve image. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I put the jsonData variable the good and the bad examples (need to uncomment it). It is clear that Hihghcharts own examples not working at all on their server.
Am I doing something wrong or why it is not working?
Thank you!
I tried a lot of things and I would like to know why the Highcharts example not works on the Highcharts export server? If it is possible I would like to get a working example with the custom JS functions. Like update title or values in the chart with JS code.

The officially deployed Export Server (https://export.highcharts.com/) does not provide features like:

custom callbacks
custom JavaScript functions
external URLs
for security reasons.

These flags:
"allowCodeExecution": false,
"allowFileResources": false

are disabled on the officially deployed server.
If you'd like to take advantage of the full range of Export Server capabilities, including custom code execution and handling external URLs, you would need to set up your own Export Server based on the guide included on GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server?tab=readme-ov-file#highcharts-nodejs-export-server
where you would enable the allowCodeExecution and allowCodeResources.
